# MVC Partial validation (ModelState.IsValid Vs ModelState.IsValidField)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In a MVC project I have a class with (let's say) 10 properties, all required. In case of user selection I have to validate only 3 properties once and all the properties other time.

Those are my properties of the class Patient:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string responsibleLastName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string responsibleFirstName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string responsibleAddressLine1;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string responsibleCityName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string responsibleStateCode;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip Code is required")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string responsiblePostalZoneOrZIPCode;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is required")]
    public DateTime responsibleBirthDate;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
    public string responsibleGenderCode;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Home Phone is required")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string responsibleHomePhone;
```

Before saving, in controller I'm doing the validation:

```
 if (firstCondition)  //partial validation
        {      if (!ModelState.IsValidField("responsibleLastName"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("responsibleLastName", "Last Name is required");
            isOK = false;
             }
              //... and 2 more validation

              //finally I check the isOK value

               if (!isOK)
                  return PartialView("firstCondition", model);
               else
                  // do something

        }
else {   //validate all the properties from the model
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("secondCondition", model);   
    else
           //do something
}
```

In the first case , my messages are duplicated for those 3 properties + all error messages for class.

ModelState.IsValidField is doing a call for Model.IsValid and is getting a list of ModelValidationResult for each property and after that check the result for the field I want? Why messages are duplicated?

I want to use model validation facility , so I don't want to validate manually the values

```
//NOT
 if (!model.responsibleLastName == "")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("responsibleLastName", "Last Name is required");
            isOK = false;
             }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a short question why are you doing validation twice once in model once in controller

Comment: I supposed that ModelState.IsValidField("responsibleLastName") is just checking the annotation from Model. As I said , I don't want to validate manually and if I use ModelState.IsValid is checking all the fields even if I need only 3.

Comment: Basically as soon as you put validation on your model like you did for all of them making all of them required the validation will be automatically binded to your view, if you assume you do not want to use validation on some of them then remove required from the model and just validate the ones you think that you might need on the client side or the way you do it

Comment: Thank you for response, but this example is a minimalistic sample of what I have. I have a model with more than 10 properties, in plus I want to use unobtrusive client validation also, that is possible using annotations from Metadata.

Comment: yes I would just use client side validation but based on the example you provided like Lastname you validating it twice once in model once in controller

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a custom `RequiredIf` validation attribute as specified in this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).